# Handling a complex CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file like:

[image: <img src="">]

I want to convert to a dictionary using Python, and the dictionary should look like:

```
[{'Type': ['Date'], 'Value': ['dd/mm/yyyy']}, 
 {'Type': ['Gender'], 'Value': ['Male', 'Female']},
 {'Type': ['Title'], 'Value': ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Ms.']}]
```

Currently I've tried the below:

```
import csv
import collections

with open('test2.csv', 'rU') as fin:
   reader = csv.DictReader(fin)

   data = []
   for row in reader:
       data.append(row)
   print data
```

And the output is:

```
[{'Type': 'Date', 'Value': 'dd/mm/yyyy'}, 
 {'Type': 'Gender', 'Value': 'Male'}, 
 {'Type': '', 'Value': 'Female'}, 
 {'Type': 'Title', 'Value': 'Mr.'}, 
 {'Type': '', 'Value': 'Mrs.'}, 
 {'Type': '', 'Value': 'Ms.'}]
```

Comment: `DictReader` turns each row into a single dictionary. If you want to aggregate across multiple rows, you should write code to do that yourself. It looks like you can check `if row['type']` to determine whether this is a brand new row, or should be used to update the last item in `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

data=[]
with open(fn, 'rU') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, dialect='excel')
    header=next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        di={k:[v] for k,v in zip(header, row)}
        if di[header[0]]==['']:
            data[-1][header[1]].extend(di[header[1]]) 
        else:
            data.append(di) 

>>> data
[{'Type': ['Date'], 'Value': ['dd/mm/yyyy']}, {'Type': ['Gender'], 'Value': ['Male', 'Female']}, {'Type': ['Title'], 'Value': ['Mr.', 'Mrs', 'Ms']}]
```

Comment: This is great. But what if I have more than two columns? I do not want to hardcode the column index.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want and an example. Otherwise I am just speculating. You can certainly extend the test of blank value to more than one column, but which ones? Same with adding data to the list above: If you have N columns, which columns are the equivalent of `'Type'` and which are equivalent to `'Value'`?

Comment: Yeah you are correct dawg. I would have given a better example. But your thought helped me to derive mine as follows:

import csv

args = ['Value']

data=[]
with open('test1.csv', 'rU') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin, dialect='excel')
    header=next(reader)
    
    for row in reader:
        di = {k:[v] for k,v in zip(header, row)}
        # print di
        if di[header[0]] == ['']:
            for arg in args:
                data[-1][arg].extend(di[arg])
        else:
            data.append(di)

print data

The args will contain the list of columns.

Answer (score 0):

sadly you can't read that in using csv.DictReader as this is very non standard format of an csv file

you will probably have to read it and parse it manually.

i assume you always expect two columns, and if the type is empty then you use the type from previous line.

as an alternative it may be worth changing the format and making the values in column A mandatory (if it's something you control), which solves some of your problems but not all, you would still have to agregate the results from csv reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

with open('test.csv','r') as test_file:
    reader = csv.reader(test_file, delimiter=',')

    output = []
    last_key = None

    for row in reader:
        if row[0]:
            last_key = row[0]
            output.append({row[0]:[row[1]]})
        else:
            output[-1][last_key].append(row[1])

pprint(output)
```

---

```
>>> 
[{'Type': ['Value']},
 {'Date': ['dd/mm/yy']},
 {'Gender': ['Male', 'Female']},
 {'Title': ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Ms.']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your csv is going to be two columns and you know that it will always be nicely grouped in the way you've shown, then it might be easiest just to build up your dictionary by hand. The trick it, when there isn't a value in the 1st column, you want to use the previously known value.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

last_key = None
data = defaultdict(list)
with open('test2.csv', 'rU') as fin:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        key, value = row[0], row[1]
        if key:
            data[key].append(value)
            last_key = key
        else:
            data[last_key].append(value)
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `csv`?

Comment: You're right, it would be better to use csv. I just wanted to show the logic. I edited my answer.